# Bulk insert data in mule

Tags: insert, mule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNR3y.png)

I want to use the insert all statement. What should I do?
No bulk model or foreach, just insert all statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert into a database you can make use of bulk insert operation available in Database Connector.